# What do colors in GUFW firewall report mean?

Tags: gufw

There are red and grey text in GUFW firewall report.

[image: gufw report screenshot]

I can't figure out what do they mean. Tried googling it up but best I could find was mention that there are "color codes" in report.

Originally I thought it's blocked applications, but nope, applications in both colors are added to the rules list.

Comment: Which report are you referring to? Could you possible include an screenshot?

Comment: Ah yes, added screenshot to original post. 
I see only one report so that's how I called it. I think it's list of running accessing network (well some of them)

Comment: @Rinzwind Would work if there was a gray one among the listed.. Rather it's not about rules, but the way report section is displayed which is why I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the GUFW `Report` tab...

Which ports are active...

RED indicates rule exists... probably accepts.

BLACK indicates no rule exists... probably blocked.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I didn't notice it's different protocol/port No rule, thanks :)